# How to update data in django model to title case in views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to change a column of strings like 'HOSPITAL ZERO', "HOSPITAL ONE" from the database into title case or 'Hospital zero' in the views.py or models.py. I've tried both and can't get either to work for me.

Here is my code in views.py. Column is in Hospital Model under name, i.e. Hospital.name.

```
def results(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
      Q=()
      out_words = request.GET.get('s')
      context = RequestContext(request)
      #here is where I tried to change it
      qs = Price.objects.annotate(hospital__name=Lower('hospital__name'))
      table = PriceTable(qs.filter(service__desc_us__icontains = out_words))
      RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 10}).configure(table)
      RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    else:
      table = PriceTable(Price.objects.all())
      RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

    return render(request, 'results.html', {'table': table})
```

Here is how I tried in model.py.

```
    class Hospital(models.Model):
        """Model representing Hospitals."""
        hid = models.CharField(max_length = 8, null=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
        hopid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular hospital in database')
        address = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)


        class Meta:
            ordering = ['hopid']
        #here is where i tried to update it
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.name = self.name.title()
            return super(Hospital, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __str__(self):
            """String for representing the Model object."""
            return f'{self.name} ({self.address})'

class Price(models.Model):
  """Model with all the hospital prices by service."""
  priceid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular service in database')
  comments = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null =True)
  hospital = models.ForeignKey("Hospital", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

  class Meta:
      ordering =['priceid']


  def __str__(self):
      return f'{self.hospital.name} (...)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a new method for your Hospital model called `get_title_case_name`. Now you can access a hospital name by calling `hospital_instance.get_title_case_name()`.

```
class Hospital(models.Model):
    """Model representing Hospitals."""
    hid = models.CharField(max_length = 8, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    hopid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular hospital in database')
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['hopid']

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.name} ({self.address})'

    def get_title_case_name(self):
        return self.name.capitalize()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The data is capitalized, I'm trying to display it as title case in my view. I dont understand your answer.

Comment: I realize that. Try the code. The capitalize() function in Python converts a string to sentence case.

Comment: You'll need to get a Hospital instance first. Once the above is in your model, get a Hospital instance: `h = Hospital.objects.all()[0]`. Then, run the function: `h.get_title_case_name()`.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I import this function into my views, because I can't seem to. I'd like to do something like this:   qs = Price.objects.annotate(hospital__name__get_title_case_name=get_title_case_name('hospital__name'))

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the Price model, because you didn't include any code for the Price model in your query. If you wanted to get the title case names of all hospitals, you could use the following in your views: return `[hospital.get_title_case_name() for hospital in Hospital.objects.all()]`.

Comment: Hospital name is the foreign key in my Price model for the Hospital model. I want to change the Hospital names to lower case. Added price model above.

Comment: Whenever you want to get the proper case for a price and hospital, just use price.hospital.get_title_case_name().

Comment: For example, try the following: `p = Price.objects.all()[0]`    `p.hospital.get_title_case_name()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
"HOSPITAL ONE".lower().capitalize()
```

`my_string.lower().capitalize()`

Here is an option:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = self.name.lower().capitalize()
        return super(Hospital, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it's not a single string. It's a column in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just add method to model:

```
def get_title_case_name(self):
        return self.name.title()
```

In views/template you can run this method against model object.

Comment: unable to import this into views. I have from Catalog.models import get_title_case_name and it's throwing an error

Comment: you don't need to import it. once you have a catalog object. you can run this method against it.